# How do i make it so it recalls the same list from dictionary in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, pickle

```
if group == "A":
    if name in groupA:
        groupA = pickle.load(open("groupA.p", "rb"))
        groupA[name] = [score]
        score.append(count)
        pickle.dump(groupA, open("groupA.p", "wb"))
    else:
        score = [count] 
        groupA[name] = [score]
        pickle.dump(groupA, open("groupA.p", "wb"))
```

This is the part of my code that is incorrect, the else statement works perfectly, but I would like to be able to recall the score saved previously into the dictionary, and then append to it, so that I can have multiple scores in my dictionary. Can someone please tell me how to do this as when I do, the following error comes up:

```
'line 83, in <module>
groupA[name] = [score]
NameError: name 'score' is not defined'
```

This makes sense, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: What should `score` be?

Comment: I think `groupA[name] = [score]` should be `score = groupA[name]`

Comment: score is a list of one or more values that comes from a variable, count. So when a number is inputted for count, that then gets added into the list for score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
dict = {'a': [1 ,2 ,3 ,4], 'b' :[1, 2]} 
dict['a'].extend([5, 6])
>> {'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'b': [1, 2]}
```

So in your code this should be like this:

```
score = [count] 
groupA[name].extend([score])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, it still comes up with the same error, how can i fix this?

Comment: when i add another value to the code, it doesn't add it to the actual list, but the dictionary will then look like {'a': [[1, 2, 3][1]]} how can i make it all add to the first bracket?

Comment: are you using `extend` or `append` to add this value?